# Will a shortcode placed inside a paragraph tag still be valid?

Tags: shortcode

I looked at some code for an article and saw that there was a shortcode contained in a `<p>` tag:

```
<p>Blabla</p>
<p>[shortcode]</p>
<p>Wofwof</p>
```

The shortcode doesn't seem to work. Could it have anything to do with that it's contained in the paragraph tag?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Wrapping a tag around a shortcode won't prevent the function from executing.

Answer (score 1):

In your page template, you may have to call do_shortcode() on the_content() inside your loop:

```
<div class"your-content>
    <?php do_shortcode( the_content() ); ?>
</div>
```